# With C# extract child <string> value from XML element

Tags: c#, xml

The following parses the data.xml file (see sample below). I can pull the body value just fine but I'm having some trouble with the recipient field. I've looped through other child elements before using this same code but not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    namespace MessagesRestore
    {
        public class ParseXml
        {
            public static void ExtractMessages()
            {
                string recepients = "";
                string body = "";

                foreach (XElement level1Element in XElement.Load(@"Data.xml").Elements("Message"))
                {
                    body = level1Element.Element("Body").Value; //Works

                    foreach (XElement level2Element in level1Element.Elements("Recepients"))
                    {
                        recepients = level2Element.Element("string").Value; //Fails
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

data.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<ArrayOfMessage>
  <Message>
    <Recepients>
      <string>5555555555</string>
    </Recepients>
    <Body>blah blah blah</Body>
    <IsIncoming>false</IsIncoming>
    <IsRead>true</IsRead>
    <Attachments />
    <LocalTimestamp>130979714416748889</LocalTimestamp>
    <Sender />
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <Recepients>
      <string>5555555555</string>
    </Recepients>
    <Body>yaba daba do</Body>
    <IsIncoming>false</IsIncoming>
    <IsRead>true</IsRead>
    <Attachments />
    <LocalTimestamp>130979673444601802</LocalTimestamp>
    <Sender />
  </Message>
  <Message>
</ArrayOfMessage>
```

Thank you,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me if you correct your XML. You have an open `<Message>` tag and no closing tag at the very bottom.

What do you get in your debugger. I get this:

[image]

Comment: I think I found my "rookie" mistake. My sample XML was only a small portion of the main file, hence the extra opening message tag I accidentally copied over.  Some "recepients" elements were null, which I wasn't testing for. After adding some validation my error went away. Sorry for the false alarm here. :| Thanks for your help though.